# To know a shortcut key in Eclipse IDE

Tags: tabs

Is there any eclispe shortcut to move back and forth the tabs like we do in browsers (next tab: ctrl+tab; previous tab: ctrl+shift+tab).. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ctrl+pageup, ctrl+pagedown keys help move from one tab to another tab in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to jump back to Last location with alt + LEFT, in addition to that ctrl + e will bring you up a menu for browsing open editor tabs. I dont know exactly if Back and forth is available.

Comment: Alt + left takes to previously edited tab and similarly Alt + right for forward. But I think there is no short-cut for exactly previous and next tab.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + F6 provides you a list of tabs to switch between them

Comment: Thanks. Ctrl+F6 is a good option but it is difficult to press it, rather we can use ctrl+e and browse thru.